# openLDAP / Sasl - ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)

Tags: ldap, openldap, sasl

I configure openldap with sasl bind.

Trying connect:

```
# ldapsearch -v -H ldaps:// -Y PLAIN -U name@example.com
```

But getting error:

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
```

1. I create a config file /etc/sasl2/slapd.conf:

```
pwcheck_method: auxprop 
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
```

2. Sample server and client show successful authentication.

```
# sasl2-sample-server -s sample -h localhost -p 1789 -m PLAIN
# sasl2-sample-client -s sample -p 1789  -m PLAIN localhost
```

```
trying 2, 1, 6
trying 10, 1, 6
bind: Address already in use
accepted new connection
forcing use of mechanism PLAIN
send: {5}
PLAIN
waiting for client mechanism...
recv: {5}
PLAIN
recv: {1}
Y
recv: {49}
name@example.com[0]name@example.com[0]xxxxx
negotiation complete
successful authentication 'name@example.com'
closing connection
```

3. slapd log:

```
 
Mar 21 18:21:20  slapd[26236]: conn=1062 fd=10 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:38312 (IP=127.0.0.1:636)
Mar 21 18:21:20  slapd[26236]: conn=1062 fd=10 TLS established tls_ssf=256 ssf=256
Mar 21 18:21:20  slapd[26236]: conn=1062 op=0 UNBIND
Mar 21 18:21:20  slapd[26236]: conn=1062 fd=10 closed
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Common errors encountered when using OpenLDAP Software, one may need to remove SASL-specific options such as `-Y ...` and enforce a "simple" authentication with `-x`.

> C.1.21. ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: ...
>
> If you intended to bind using a DN and password and get an error from ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s, you likely forgot to provide a '-x' option to the command. By default, SASL authentication is used. '-x' is necessary to select "simple" authentication.

https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin26/appendix-common-errors.html